# How to publish shapefiles with GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, shapefile

I have multiple shapefiles of my country, its states and cities. I want them to display in map i.e. First layer is country, then states-layer and then cities layer.

I only know that to do this, first of all these files have to be uploaded in GeoServer, installed on Server, then somehow GeoServer is requested to give desired shapefiles.

Please help me how it can be done i.e. upload files in GeoServer, How to request it and add shapefile into web page.

Answer (score 2):

There is a **[Publishing a Shapefile](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/gettingstarted/shapefile-quickstart/)** tutorial available online for GeoServer that seems to describe the steps you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Very Good Tutorial, that how can you publish shape file to geoserver.
Here you will find step by step guide to publish multiple shape file. As per you case where publishing of country and state shape file are required with grouping of each other.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiH4K1NLOZA